# How to find work done when external force is doing work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, work

> A heat conducting piston can freely move inside a closed thermally insulated cylinder of volume $2v_0$ filled with an ideal gas. In equilibrium, the piston divides the cylinder into two equal parts and the gas temperature is $T_0$. The piston is slowly displaced by an external force. Find the heat absorbed/released by both the chambers when the ratio of the two chambers becomes $n:1$.

In this so far I had calculated the final temperature of the system, by writing **work done by external force** from work energy theorem and using equation of state for the gas, but now to calculate heat, I need to calculate work done by the gas on individual chamber (as change in internal energy can be easily calculated), here is where I am confused because what is actually work done by the gas on both individual chambers; would it be same or different?

PS - This is **not a homework question**, indeed the question was only up to finding final temperature, but I extended it to this one !!

Comment: What is your problem?  It seems straightforward.

Comment: Lets say Piston moved from part 1 to part 2 , let pressure in part 1 be p1 and in part 2 be p2 ; now if change in volume is dV then work done by the gas in part 1 would be p1.dV or  p1.dV + dW(by external force) ? that's my doubt ?

Comment: The work done by the gas in part 1 is p1dV

Comment: So , would the work done on the gas in part 1 be -(p2dV - dW) ? which is same as -p1dV ?

Comment: If you got the songs right, then Yes.

Comment: I guess u mean "signs" :D

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant.

Comment: Ok , Thanks very much , Got my doubts cleared !